# Image Editing Library for Android

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I have a basic requirement for a simple image editing app for android.
After displaying the image the user must be able to set alpha of the image , choose 
brightness , set contrast.

For achieving this task i have tried the following libraries :-
1. [JJIL](https://code.google.com/p/jjil/)
2. Android Image Filtering
3. [Aviary SDK](http://www.aviary.com/)

For JJIL i am facing problem importing the projects.
For Android Image Filtering , there isnt much documentation available.
Using Aviary i can achieve this but it has the aviary logo and using this SDK the user can 
choose get more features options and navigate to aviary app in app store.

Which is the better way of doing this ? shall i use a library or i should use native android color class ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try my PhotoEditor library https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor

Answer (score 4):

- Use GPUImage if you want to use **[OpenGL](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage)** (fastest I know)
- You can use [**Image Effect Pro**](https://github.com/yaa110/Effects-Pro) which uses pure **Java** ( relatively slower) image processing.
- You can also try [**Fast Image Processing Library**](https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing/tree/master/framework/FastImageProcessing/src/project/android/imageprocessing/filter) (OpenGL based)
- You can read more about Image Processing stuffs from **[here](https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/reflected-image-view/)** and **[here](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/tag/processing/)**

Answer (score 2):

We at Img.ly have released an image editing SDK for Android as part of our PhotoEditorSDK product suite. It includes all the functions you mentions and is easily [customizable](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v6_6/customization/introduction)

You can find a demo application [here](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo). You can use the library for free in your open source projects, but there is a license fee for commercial applications.